# difference between setLabelCol and setPredictionCol methods in spark MLib

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I was using logistic regression for classification in spark Mlib, what is difference between `setLabelCol(`) and `setPredictionCol()` method in spark ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are two methods to set non default column names for label and prediction

- `setLabelCol` (default="label") is used to set the column name for the label at **training** time. E.G. When training a binary classifier you need a 'label' containing either 1.0 or 0.0. The algorithm will use that to train a Model.
- `setPredicionCol` (default="prediction") is used to set the column name for the output of the Model at **scoring** time. E.G. Your binary classifier model trained above will add a new column to your DataFrame containing the predicted output.

You could use `explainParams` to take a look at available params, default values, and brief doc. E.G.

```
scala> new LogisticRegression().explainParams
res6: String = 
...
featuresCol: features column name (default: features)
...
labelCol: label column name (default: label)
...
predictionCol: prediction column name (default: prediction)
probabilityCol: Column name for predicted class conditional probabilities. 
...
```